# web.config file setting in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

explain session type =sql server'

Comment: I think you forgot a few words... try expanding your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That allows session data to be stored in SQL Server. See this [knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604) for a fuller description of the procedure.

Answer (score 2):

It's used to determine where you store your session variables, in this case a SQL Server.

You can read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx).

EDIT: And even more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nice article about [Exploring Session in ASP.Net](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ExploringSession.aspx#21). Have you ever used Google? We are more than welcome to help newbies but questions in this format is not encouraged ;-) Please explain more about your requirement.